# how to set a dataflow from influxdb to hdfs in nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

In nifi `PutInfluxdb` processor is there to send data to Influxdb...
But there is nothing like a `fetchInfluxdb`/`ConsumeInfluxdb` processor. Then how to push data from Influxdb to hdfs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NiFi versions till 1.6.0 doesn't have a processor to read from InfluxDB. There is a Jira to have a similar processor called `ExecuteInfluxDbQuery` and it is merged to the master. It will be available with NiFi 1.7.0.

Take a look at [NIFI-4927](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4927)

Comment: Can `ExecuteInfluxDbQuery` be added to Nifi 1.6 ? @Sivaprasanna Sethuraman

Comment: It can be added but I think some changes might be required. The 1.7.0 version introduces a new concept `ExpressionLanguageScope` which is not available in versions < 1.6.0. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4149. The required changes are not major per se, just a few lines need to be edited

Comment: Apart from Nifi, So is there any way to push data from influxdb to hdfs ?

Comment: You can write a Java code to do that. Ultimately NiFi processors are also doing that with the help of the relevant SDKs, in this case, influxdb-java and hdfs. I would suggest you rather than building something from scratch, you can just build the latest master branch from NiFi and use it. That's the quickest approach I can think of.